# Disable XHTML validation in Netbeans for dojo developing

Tags: netbeans, xhtml, dojo

I am developing a dojo application in Netbeans 7.1, however since dojo uses non standard HTML attributes, I have XHTML validation errors in every line.
Within Netbeans there is the option to completely ignore this errors for a specific line or for the whole document, bu I would like to keep basic html validation on.
Is it possible to have this errors ignored without loosing html validation ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dojo supports also valid `data-` HTML attributes, use those:

- `data-dojo-config` not `djConfig`, e.g.: `data-dojo-config="parseOnLoad:true,async:true"`
- `data-dojo-type` instead of `dojoType`
- `data-dojo-props` e.g.: `data-dojo-props="name:'start_date',required: true"`
- `data-dojo-attach-point` in widget templates
- `data-dojo-attach-event` in widget templates
- `data-dojo-id` instead of `jsId`

**Edit**: Since `data-*` attributes are valid only in HTML5 and NetBeans validates documents according to `doctype` you can also fine-tune validation via menu `Tools` » `Options` » `Editor` » `Hints` » `HTML`. There turn off or change *Show As* of `Elements`. You will need to reopen html documents to apply new validation rules

[image]

Comment: Changing the attribute name doesn't help, same message `Attribute data-dojo-type not allowed on XHTML element "div" at this point`.

Comment: It is probable NetBeans is validating against your `doctype`. Custom `data-` attributes are valid in HTML5 I use, so it validates my markup including those `data-dojo-*` attributes. I found out how to allow customize HTML validation, so I am going to edit my answer.